# How to properly work with mixed gerrit/github repositories?

Tags: git, openssh

I work with a git repo with lots of submodules. Some of them are on corporate github, others on Gerrit.

Recently, I started having problems that plink didn't accept the server key anymore. So I switched to openssh, which works. Ideally, I would like to fix the plink issue, but for now I opted with the openssh workaround.

The issue I have is that:

1) If I don't give a username to ssh, it just uses my windows username (which includes the domain)
2) If I specify a username in GIT_SSH_COMMAND, then it uses that for all git connections, regardless of whether the remote url specifies something else. So the git@github urls don't work.
3) I could specify the username in the remotes for the gerrit repos, but I'd like to avoid that as there are lots of repos

Is 3) the only option I have here? How can I solve this dilemma?

Answer (score 0):

My project actually documented that but I forgot to properly configure it:

You can set the user used by openssh for a certain server in ~/.ssh/config:

```
Host gerrit.my.server
  User myUser
```

That allows me to configure this once for the server instead of each repository, and I solve the problem that it tries to connect with domain+username.